# mbsctows to count the number of wide characters in an array

Tags: c

I am currently working on UNIX and COBOL and have hit an requirement where I need to provide the number of chinese and korean characters in the received message which I plan to accomplish in C program using mbstows.

I am using the below code which is not giving the correct count for the chinese double byte characters but giving the byte count.

```
#include <wchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) /* argc should be 2 for correct execution */
    {
        /* We print argv[0] assuming it is the program name */
        printf( "usage: %s filename", argv[0] );
    }
    int Size = getCharCount(argv[1]);
    printf ("THE CHAR COUNT  %d", Size);
    return Size;
}
int getCharCount(char *argv)
{
    wchar_t *wcsVal = NULL;     
    char *mbsVal = NULL;
    char* localeInfo;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.GB18030");

    /* verify locale is set */      
    if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == 0)      
    {
        /*                      printf(stderr, "Failed to set locale\n"); */
        return 1;
    }
    mbsVal = argv;
    printf (" MBSVAL %s\n", mbsVal);
    /* validate multibyte string and convert to wide character */

    int size = mbstowcs(NULL, mbsVal, 0);
    if (size == -1)
    {         
        printf("Invalid multibyte\n");         
        return 1;
    }
    return size; 
}
```

Appreciate your kind response...

Regards

Akm

Answer (score 3):

Setting the locale to a specific value chosen by the programmer in order to process a particular character set is incorrect usage. Not only are locale names implementation-specific; they're also intended to reflect the user's or system's character encoding.

If you need to programmatically process a particular character encoding, the `iconv` interface exists for this purpose. Use `iconv_open("WCHAR_T", "GB18030");` to obtain a conversion descriptor, and convert a couple kb at a time into a throwaway buffer on the stack, summing up the number of output characters obtained from each run.

Comment: BTW, I know `iconv` is POSIX and not plain C, but OP's question was using `setlocale` with arguments that suggest this code is running on a Unix-like system, probably GNU/Linux. And unlike non-portable arguments to `setlocale`, it's possible to drop in your own `iconv` library if your system doesn't have `iconv`.

Answer (score 1):

Your line:

```
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "") == 0)
```

will reset the LOCALE to the values set in environment variables, so maybe not the chinese character set anymore. Try to remove it or check environment variables values.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your response. I tried commenting out the mentioned code, but the code still would not work. The input I am trying to give to this program is : ½»Í¨ÒøÐÐÉÏº£ÐÂÇøÖ§ÐÐ Which is a byte stream of double bytes chinese characters. It actually has 20 bytes but my C program should identify that they are chinese characters and provide me the count as 10 since they are double byte characters. Any response will be very highly appreciated... Thanks in advance...

Comment: Are you sure the locale that you set is installed on your system? If you do the set of LC_ALL or LC_CTYPE in a shell, is it accepted by the OS?

Comment: Hi, I complied the program and was able to run successfully... Only thing is that it is not recogizing the chinese character set in the input byte stream of double byte characters..... I tried using the below - if (setlocale(LC_ALL, "zh_CN.GB18030") == 0) { printf("Failed to set locale\n"); return 1; }

Comment: You probably need to add some package to support this locale. Try running locale -a to list installed locales on your system.

Comment: Hi Benoit, Thanks a Lot.... Your suggestion really worked... I tried locale -a to get the available locales and found that the character z in zh_CN.GB18030 was in caps... Zh_CN.GB18030...Now the program is able to provide the correct character count... Million thanks once again for your suggestion...